# how to get table cell value while Parsing with XPath, and the cell contain value like <19.00 OR >23.99

Tags: html, xpath, domparser

actually i need to parse a HTML table and that table contains HTML character, you can see in image.

i need each cell data with that special character also. Right now when i am parsing the table with XPath its ignore that cell and returns that cell value as empty.

Both Image attached here.[image: Main Table]
[image: Parsed DOM Object]

```
$table_head = $summary_nodes->childNodes->item(0);
$table_body = $summary_nodes->childNodes->item(1);
$head = [];
$body = [];
// print_r($table_head);
foreach($table_head->childNodes as $h_index => $h_node){
    $head_temp = [];
    foreach($h_node->childNodes as $cell_index => $cell){
        $head_temp[] = trim($cell->nodeValue);
    }
    $head[] = $head_temp;
}
foreach($table_body->childNodes as $b_index => $b_node){
    $body_temp = [];
    // print_r($b_node);
    foreach($b_node->childNodes as $cell_index => $cell){
        print_r($cell);
        $body_temp[] = trim($cell->nodeValue);
    }
    $body[] = $body_temp;
}
return ['table_ready'=>array_merge([$head[count($head)-1]], $body), 'headers'=> $head];
```

Comment: Please show us the actual HTML code, not just a screenshot.

Comment: $file_url = $dir.'/index.html';
                $doc = new DOMDocument();
                libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
                @$doc->loadHTMLFile($file_url);
                echo "<pre>";
                // print_r($doc);return;
                $xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
                $main_container = $xpath->query("//div[@id='cont']/div");

Comment: @JLRishe Please se that last line after query the result not having that cell value

Comment: What I meant was please edit the question to show the HTML for the table that's involved in this. What you just posted here in the comments isn't HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Hello friends I got answer for this, actually what is happening we are adding HTML entity inside our real data that's why while passing it's conflicting with HTML content and while parsing parser remove automatically that HTML entities so we have to make sure our real data does not have any HTML entities if we are using or if we need any entity which is similar to HTML entity please try to use they are HTML entity code.